# Yahoo Vespa Create a search definition in runtime

Tags: search, yahoo, vespa

I would like to know if there is any API in "vespa platform" which I can use to create a search definition (sd) in runtime.

This is a requirement, because the documents that I will index are depending on the user input in my front end application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such API available. The idea of deploying an immutable application package (including the SD) is a conscious design choice to ensure appropriate management of multiple search clusters in multiple locations over time as well as enabling source control management.

If needed, one could build what you describe "on top" of Vespa: A web service that will let you mutate an existing SD and, upon submit, create the updated application package and deploy to your Vespa cluster. Vespa will (in most cases) handle schema changes without impacting serving.